# Wrapping text to the next line after a fullstop or condition?

Tags: javascript, css

Is it possible to move text to the next line after a full stop?

For example with a standard h1 header - 'This is a very. Very. Big header.'

But I want my headers to move to the next line after a fullstop -

'This is a very.

Very.

Big header.'

My goal is to have every title h1 fetched from an API to for formatted so the line wraps every time there is a fullstop '.'

Code:

```js
<div className='quote-wrapper'>
    <h1 className='quote'>{currentQuote.quote}</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: what have you tried so far ? please post the code

Comment: I've added the code I'm doing it in React though. I haven't tried anything because I do not have a single clue if it's even possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by using the split method.
Here is how i did it.
https://code.sololearn.com/W85wKQly9I7a/?ref=app

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there is a way this can be achieved as a CSS style or HTML property. Look into [`word-wrap`](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_word-wrap.asp) and [`text-overflow`](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_text-overflow.asp) incase they work for you, though.

In JavaScript, this is easy. Just find all the elements you want to change (like all `h1`'s, get their current text with `.innerText` or `.innerHtml`, and then set their current text to be their old text but replace all the periods with newlines.

```js
document.querySelectorAll("h1").forEach((x) => {
  x.innerText = x.innerText.replace(/\./g, "\n")
})
```

Here, `document.querySelectorAll("h1")` gets a list of all `h1`'s on the page. You could make it something like `".quote"` to select by class, etc.

`forEach(...)` takes a function (the `(x) => {...}` thing) and applies it to each item in the list.

In our function `x.innerText` is the text inside the `h1` element and `replace` replaces everything matching the first argument (`/\./g`) with the second argument (`"\n"`). Here, `/\./g` is the regular expression for "all periods" and `"\n"` is the newline character.

---

Edit:

It looks like you are using React so you don't actually need to do anything with a querySelector. Just perform the replace on `currentQuote.quote` right before you put it into the DOM